# How to bind an SVG DOM Element in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have an SVG DOM Element Object that I would like to manage using the Svelte syntax (for example, adding a class). That Element only exists in memory, in the sense that it's not appended to the body, therefore it is not visible on the page.

```js
<script>
  // Create an SVG element
  let mySvg1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  mySvg1.setAttribute("width", "100");
  mySvg1.setAttribute("height", "100");

  // Create a circle element
  let circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  circle.setAttribute("cx", "50");
  circle.setAttribute("cy", "50");
  circle.setAttribute("r", "40");
  circle.setAttribute("fill", "red");

  // Append the circle to the SVG element
  mySvg1.appendChild(circle);
</script>
```

```css
<style>
  #myThing {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

I tried binding it like this

```html
<svg id="myThing" bind:this={mySvg1}></svg>
```

But nothing appears on the page, and the SVG Element is not visible to the inspector.

***Appending it to the body*** using `document.body.appendChild(mySvg1)` ***isn't a fix*** , because this creates a second SVG, that doesn't have the same content as the first.

The red circle doesn't show up INSIDE the blue square, which means the SVG with ID "myThing" isn't bound with the mySvg1 DOM Element.

[image: screenshot]

Reminder that you can copy and paste my code on Svelte's repl https://svelte.dev/repl

So I end up with two SVGs Element instead of one, what can I do about it?

---

I tried with an action

```
<script>
  function generateSvg() {
    // Create an SVG element
    let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.setAttribute("width", "100");
    svg.setAttribute("height", "100");

    // Create a circle element
    let circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    circle.setAttribute("cx", "50");
    circle.setAttribute("cy", "50");
    circle.setAttribute("r", "40");
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "red");

    // Append the circle to the SVG element
    svg.appendChild(circle);

    return svg;
  }

  function replaceSvg(svg) {
    let generatedSvg = generateSvg();
    svg.parentNode.replaceChild(generatedSvg, svg);
  }

</script>

<svg id="myThing" use:replaceSvg />
```

And with `onMount`

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let mySvg1; // Declare the variable

  // This is important, I'm using a library that behaves like this function and I cannot modify it. The functions return a newly created DOM Element Object. 
  function generateSvg() {
    // Create an SVG element
    let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.setAttribute("width", "100");
    svg.setAttribute("height", "100");

    // Create a circle element
    let circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    circle.setAttribute("cx", "50");
    circle.setAttribute("cy", "50");
    circle.setAttribute("r", "40");
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "red");

    // Append the circle to the SVG element
    svg.appendChild(circle);

    return svg;
  }

  onMount(() => {
    // Manually create an SVG element
    mySvg1 = generateSvg()

    // Don't know what to do next
  });
  
</script>

<!-- Don't know what to do next --> 
<svg id="myThing" bind:this={mySvg1} />
```

No luck here, in both cases, the SVG doesn't show up in the inspector.

Comment: Why are you creating the elements programmatically in the first place? Usually you can just use things like `#if` and `#each` in the `svg` markup instead. (That's the whole point of Svelte - making UIs dynamic *and* declarative.)

Comment: Good and of course expected question, I cannot do this because I'm using a private library that generates SVGs as DOM Elements. I cannot just type in the SVG code, the library generates it for me. I added document.createElementNS in my example instead of the library factory method but it's what it's using under the hood.

Comment: Regarding the edit: You are always overwriting the SVG (`mySvg1 = document.createElementNS(...)`. Do not do that. There also is no need to set `width` and `height` in the code, just do it in markup on the existing SVG.

Comment: Also, read the code carefully, the action gets the SVG as an argument. You are completely ignoring that. It does not require a local variable.

Comment: You are right about the action, I got rid of the mySvg1 variable completely and only used the argument. But I'm not sure what to do next, I tried to `return svg` at the end but nothing happened.

About overwriting in the onMount example, I'm also not sure what I should do if I cannot use `mySvg1 = document.createElementNS(...)`. Why is that an issue?

Comment: With `bind:this` you can **get** an element from the DOM, not write to it. If you want to insert an SVG as a whole, you need a container. I added a note about that to my answer.

Comment: You are *still* overwriting the `svg` variable in the `modifySvg` action, just don't. `svg` already is an SVG. Same with `bind:this`, `mySvg1` already is an SVG. If you overwrite it, you just create another SVG in memory that does not exist anywhere else.

Comment: How can I set the content of the variable without overwriting it? I'm a bit clueless

Comment: I managed to have it work with a appendSvg action using `div.appendChild(svg)`  within the function, it made sense but this means that I cannot access the `<svg>` (because we use a container) right?

Comment: You can declare and assign a local variable (outside the function) for later access. You just have to be careful about the order of operations.

Comment: As I understand it, in my `onMount` example `mySvg1` is set only when the component mounts, and then the variable content never changes and stays the same (the reference to a DOM Element created by `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")`.

If my understanding is correct, why doesn't the SVG show up?

Comment: Did you add it to the DOM? Either you take an existing SVG and modify it, or when creating it manually, it has to be added to an existing container. You either messed up the references or did not add it.

Comment: By "add it to the DOM" do you mean `document.body.appendChild(mySvg1)`? I updated the onMount code

Comment: I don't. Re-read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: I edited the code again. I was thinking at first that `<svg id="myThing" bind:this={mySvg1} />` would not create a new SVG if bind was on. Is this what you had in mind for the action? I replaced the reference with a newly generated SVG but that seems ugly, I'm creating a extra SVG that I don't need just for that. To me that's why using bind is the way to go.

Comment: But I still don't understand how I could make it work with bind. I could remove the part where I create the SVG using Javascript, that way I would create it only using the HTML syntax, bind, and during onMount append the children to the SVG but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm using a function that create the SVG Element before hand, I modified the code with a generateSvg function to make that clear

Comment: I clearly stated, that if you want to append an entire SVG, you create a container and append to that instead. Either using a binding + `onMount` or using an action. Why would you create a pointless SVG in the markup if you create your **actual** SVG in code? It's really not that complicated.

Comment: Can you please take my binding + onMount example, modify it, and add it to your answer below so I can see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `bind:this`, you have to wait for the element to be mounted via `onMount`.

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let mySvg1; // bind:this target

    onMount(() => {
      // ...create circle...

      mySvg1.appendChild(circle);
    });
</script>
```

Or use [an action](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-action) instead:

```html
<script>
    function modifySvg(svg) {
        // ...create circle...

        svg.appendChild(circle);
    }
</script>

<svg id="myThing" width="100" height="100" use:modifySvg  />
```

If you want to add an SVG as a whole within the component, you need *some* container for it. E.g. a `div`.

```html
<div style="display:contents" use:appendSvg />
```

The action would be passed the `div` which the SVG can be appended to.
Likewise `bind:this` could be used to obtain a reference to the `div` and then add to it in `onMount`.

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let div;
  let svg;

  function generateSvg() {
    const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    // ...
    return svg;
  }

  onMount(() => {
    svg = generateSvg()
    div.appendChild(svg);
  });
</script>

<div style="display:contents" bind:this={div} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! But you're not going to like this as I'm already using your patience a lot  Are you saying that it's not possible to bind the SVG itself, not a div or any other container, the SVG itself?

You're doing this : `<div style="display:contents" bind:this={div} />`
But I want this : `<svg style="display:contents" bind:this={svg} />`

If indeed we can't, why not? Can't the HTML declaration append to the DOM itself and feed in the content taken from the bind/variable?

Comment: `<svg ...>` creates an SVG, you already create the SVG in code, it's not compatible. Either you just create the SVG in markup and only append contents to it (not **another** SVG) or you have a container and add an entire SVG to that. There are no other options if you want to retain the elements created by whatever library you are using. If you don't need the SVG element created by the library you could extract the children from it and only append those to the SVG you created in the markup.